# How to provide blob storage account details while uploading video into windows azure media service?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I have master windows azure account which contains blob storage. In this blob storage all my clients will upload video.

Now for each client, I will create seperate windows azure media service account + streaming endpoint.

Now how to set my master windows azure blob storage account credentials while uploading video into different streaming accounts?

I have gone through many articles but none of them are providing option to set from code side. From windows azure UI, you can set only blob account which is already exists in your account or create new one but in my scenario, my blob is in account1 while media service account is in account2, account3.... accountN.

Comment: why not creating an storage account on each subscription (programatically or not) ?

Comment: Yes i can but my all data lies under single storage account

Comment: If i do this, this will make my application & maintenance unnecessary complicated

Answer (score 1):

Upload from existing storage account to azure media services covered in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-copying-existing-blob/

When your application will grow you need to consider use multiple storage accounts not to hit limits associated with one storage account. Since you are provisioning multiple media accounts for your customers, you will have separated storage accounts associated with them. I would suggest to utilize these storage accounts from beginning and  provide your clients upload tools which will upload  directly to provisioned storage accounts without having additional hoops.

If for some reasons you still need to have one storage shared across all your customers to do initial ingest, than you can take a look into sample https://github.com/AzureMediaServicesSamples/Media-Services-Azure-Functions. This git repo demonstrate how to use azure functions to ingest video into media services when new video detected in specified  storage account.